# Какие символы нужно экранировать для защиты от SQL-инъекций?

Tags: sql, безопасность, sql-injection

В уроке по безопасности был рассмотрен механизм SQL-инъекций, однако рекомендации по защите них были даны только для числовых значений (конкретнее: числовые query-параметры изначально строчные, потому прежде чем интерполировать их в SQL-запрос, нужно попытаться привести их к числу, и тогда если будут посторонние символы, то можно вернуть какой-нибудь ошибочный HTTP-статус не запрашивая ничего из базы данных).

А как же быть строчными параметрами? Полагаю, что нужно как минимум экранировать символы, с помощью которых злоумышленник может изменить SQL-запрос. Но какие именно?

Comment: Не стоит ничего экранировать самостоятельно, отдайте заботу о защите вашей библиотеке для работы с БД (подготовленные запросы, подстановки и т.п.), она сама знает, что и как нужно делать

Comment: *Полагаю, что нужно как минимум экранировать символы, с помощью которых злоумышленник может изменить SQL-запрос.* `OR TRUE` не содержит никаких "подозрительных" символов, но при прямой подстановке способен натворить...

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю Вас за ответ. А если я сам пишу библиотеку? Если бы всё было так просто, я такие вопросы бы не задавал :)

Comment: @Akina, ясно, то есть нужно также и и SQL-операторы проверять...

Comment: Как уже сказали, используйте параметризованные запросы. Однако, если используется _динамический_ sql, то потребность в экранировании возникает. Но дело в том, что в каждой РСУБД свои правила. И, соответственно, следует использовать средства самой СУБД. Например, в Sql Server есть функция `QUOTENAME` ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15))